# T-SQL Count records over bucketed time window with zero fill

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I have a table in SQL Server 2012 that contains call detail records. A simplified version of the schema is shown in [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/11955/5).

It's trivial to count calls for a given region, but I would like to further break the data down into discrete half-hour buckets. I am then feeding the data into a chart, so I need the query to be able to return all buckets, even if there we no calls in those buckets.

Any thoughts?

Additionally, I can't lose the offsets on those values (note they are `DATETIMEOFFSET` type).  Most solutions I've found out there involve throwing away that data because they can only handle DATETIME.

Comment: add an outer join to a table (even if it's the same one) that contains the region and the 1/2 hour buckets.  The challenge will be making up data when no such data exists.  Similar to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329722/sql-server-displaying-missing-dates for dates or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375111/sql-query-to-return-24-hour-hourly-count-even-when-no-values-exist for hours. or even http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909015/find-missing-time-intervals-in-a-table

Comment: That's the trick. I can do all sorts of methods to get the raw half hour bucketed data.  The challenge here is getting the zero-fill for the buckets in which there is no data.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dim_time table or something to that extent and insert time ranges into this table (one for each half hour slot, can automate this population).

```
select time_id, time_start, time_end
from dim_time
```

Now you have a table with all the time slots you are interested in...left join it to a count query to get the counts associated to that time slot.

Once your code is in...you can alter this to 15 minute blocks, or 2 hours blocks or whatever, by manipulating the dim_time entries.

Comment: This should be ephemeral data. The query can be run for arbitrary times, but is generally only used on a one-off basis for the past 24 hours or somesuch. I would rather write a manual loop in the application to do this work than have a table whose sole purpose is marking off every half hour from the beginning of the source table to the end of eternity.

Comment: You would only need 48 entries (24 * 2 30 minute windows)...it's only the time, no date.  But 48 entries isn't too challenging to create at rune time.